# Showing GNU screen session name and window title in shell prompt

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, prompt

Is there a way to present the GNU Screen session name and window title in the prompt of the shell (let us say, the Bash prompt defined by `PS1`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Screen supplies some environment variables (from `screen`(1) manpage):

```
STY              Alternate socket name.
WINDOW           Window number of a window (at creation time).
```

The "at creation time" means that if you renumber a window (using screen's `number` command), the shell will not be told about the change and $WINDOW will still be the same as the first window number.

You could use something like:

```
PS1='\u@\h(${STY}:${WINDOW}):\w$ '
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. BTW, there is a way to get the window title, instead of the window number?

Comment: Not that I know of, there is no api for screen, and when you issue commands there is no output - it goes to the current window in the screen.  For example `screen -xr 2466 -X windows`.

Comment: Although it probably falls under the renumbering case, is there a way to access the window's name if it's set with `Ctrl-a A` ?

Comment: If GNU `screen` has been compiled with the `-Q` (query) option, then you can run some commands, such as `title` and `windows` and have the data display to stdout, however, without a trailing newline.

Answer (score 5):

I always use precise screen session names.  Then I can add screen's STY env var, with the numeric id stripped out (thanks dimo414), to PS1.  I don't decorate it with curly braces or anything because I'm not always in a session.  Simple example:

```
PS1='\u@\h ${STY#[0-9]*.} \w$ '
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
(`echo ${STY} | sed -e 's/[0-9]*\.//g'`:${WINDOW}:`screen -Q title`)
```

removes the process number from `${STY}`
includes the window number (as mentioned "at creation time")
includes the window title (as returned from `screen -Q title`)

notes:

- first time it runs, `screen -Q` waits for a return keystroke
- i set the window title with C-a C-A and then source my .profile to update the prompt

Comment: Using `${STY#[0-9]*.}` avoids needing to pipe through `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use named screens, e.g.: `screen -S vim   ## see: screen -h`

To get a PS1 prompt in the screen that shows the name of the screen session (to differentiate screen sessions for the normal terminal sessions) I needed a two-part approach.

1. Set the prompt in a `~/.screenrc` file.
2. Source that file (within the screen session) via a normal BASH `~/.bashrc` alias.

```bash
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ~/.screenrc    ## or whatever you want to name it

PS1='[\u@\h (screen: ${STY#[0-9]*.}) \w]$ '
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```bash
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ~/.bashrc

alias ssrc='source ~/.screenrc'    ## or whatever you named it (comment above)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Usage:

```bash
[me@vps1360 ~]$ screen -S test

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Named screen session:

  [me@vps1360 ~]$ ssrc
  [me@vps1360 (screen: test) ~]$    ## PS1 prompt with screen session name
  # Ctrl-a d
  [detached from 9278.test]
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[me@vps1360 ~]$
```

Comment: You could probably get away with using something like this in your `bashrc` file and forget about the alias and the `screenrc` file: `PS1='[\u@\h ${STY+(screen: ${STY#[0-9]*.}) }\w]$ '`.  It adds the parenthesis in the prompt if `STY` is set.  Also, you never have to export `PS1`.

Comment: I didn't know about `screen -S`. Thanks!

Comment: I tried various combinations of sourcing from `~.bashrc` (`alias screen='screen -c <pathToFile> ...`, `~/.screenrc`, `/etc/screenrc/`.  Part of the issue, I believe, is that screen sessions are instances of an existing (single) screen process?  Anyway, ... in the end the approach above was the simplest, facile solution. ;-)